# Password Strength Meter

Tags: javascript, passwords

I have a situation where I would like to be able to rate a users password in the web interface to my system, so that before they hit submit they know if they have a bad password.

Key Requirements:

- Must be able to rate the password, not just pass/fail.
- Should disable the form if the password is below a threshhold, so the user can't submit it.
- Look nice. :)
- Not use jQuery - we're currently using Mochikit and Y!UI in this system.

I've found many password meters written in jQuery, and things like http://www.passwordmeter.com/ that are too verbose.

Can anyone suggest a good drop in javascript password rater I can use, or give an example of how to write one?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn

Comment: This is how keepass does it in C# https://github.com/dlech/KeePass2.x/blob/b2ab2338d35352b9bc758df1aa0ea6fe9c226a49/KeePassLib/Cryptography/QualityEstimation.cs

Comment: "Closed as not constructive"? I found this very constructive indeed. Viewed 58,000+ times, top Google rank, etc. Come on folks...

Comment: If you do use a password strength meter, make sure to test it with basic sanity checking. `V4cc!nat!0n#3` is an horrifically weak password *(cracked less than an hour)*, while `monitor coke cursor fat` is extraordinarily strong *(cracked in 146,000 centuries).* Make sure the password checker you use is giving valid results *(i.e. complexity requirements make passwords weaker, not stronger)*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a collection of scripts:
http://webtecker.com/2008/03/26/collection-of-password-strength-scripts/
[(archived link)](https://web.archive.org/web/20200812221239/http://webtecker.com/2008/03/26/collection-of-password-strength-scripts/)

I think both of them rate the password and don't use jQuery... but I don't know if they have native support for disabling the form?

Comment: Remember, even if you disable the form in javascript, you should run this check on the server-side as well.  Tricksy users will just do form submits anyway, or what if a user has javascript disabled?

Comment: You should also note that users are only tricking *themselves*. Don't sure if you need to protect users from that ...

Comment: I think the page you linked was hacked... LOL! the irony

Comment: link provided is not working..

Answer (score 249):

**Update**: created a js fiddle here to see it live: http://jsfiddle.net/HFMvX/

I went through tons of google searches and didn't find anything satisfying. i like how passpack have done it so essentially reverse-engineered their approach, here we go:

```
function scorePassword(pass) {
    var score = 0;
    if (!pass)
        return score;

    // award every unique letter until 5 repetitions
    var letters = new Object();
    for (var i=0; i<pass.length; i++) {
        letters[pass[i]] = (letters[pass[i]] || 0) + 1;
        score += 5.0 / letters[pass[i]];
    }

    // bonus points for mixing it up
    var variations = {
        digits: /\d/.test(pass),
        lower: /[a-z]/.test(pass),
        upper: /[A-Z]/.test(pass),
        nonWords: /\W/.test(pass),
    }

    var variationCount = 0;
    for (var check in variations) {
        variationCount += (variations[check] == true) ? 1 : 0;
    }
    score += (variationCount - 1) * 10;

    return parseInt(score);
}
```

Good passwords start to score around 60 or so, here's function to translate that in words:

```
function checkPassStrength(pass) {
    var score = scorePassword(pass);
    if (score > 80)
        return "strong";
    if (score > 60)
        return "good";
    if (score >= 30)
        return "weak";

    return "";
}
```

you might want to tune this a bit but i found it working for me nicely

Comment: +1 because this method rates the passwords the same way [zxcvbn](https://tech.dropbox.com/2012/04/zxcvbn-realistic-password-strength-estimation/) does, but with much less code: `qwER43@!` => scores 70 = good, `Tr0ub4dour&3` => scores 80 = strong, `correcthorsebatterystaple` => scores 86 = strong.

Comment: I tuned it by giving restriction on nonWord characters awarded (because RACF restricts special characters to @#$) and allowed up to 30% occurences of the same character without score reduction as proposed by http://geodsoft.com/howto/password/pwcheck_instructions.htm

Comment: how can I tune it such, that alphabetical or numeric sequences like abcde... or 12345... are punished by minus score?

Comment: @abimelex - i think you are misreading the code, each unique symbol gets 5 points and then it's value diminishes with each repetition. i updated the answer to include a live example http://jsfiddle.net/HFMvX/

Comment: I've rewritten this function in PHP for checking the score on the server too: http://pastie.org/8889985

Comment: This is much better than the other answers. It ranks "eriahrieudfklsvhnsreuilvnreuhgsldhhvf" about twice as strong as "123&$aA"

Comment: Looking at https://www.grc.com/haystack.htm pointed out by @Ziggy and experimenting the big weakness of this solution is that it says that passwords of length less than 8 are weak or good when they are way too small. adding the following to the top of `checkPassStrength(pass)` plugs the weakness `if( pass.length < 8 ) { return "poor"; }` that encourages folks to use something long enough with mixed up characters which is going to be weak, good or strong depending on how long it is. anything less is truly poor.

Comment: This is just the snippet I was looking for. Snippets like these help **when you're already done with the design** and are just looking for an algorithm plugin..

Edit: Just found out you can't use both bold and italics to the same text while commenting!

Comment: great answer! I was curious about how it scores [pass, pass123, 'dice ware one two', ...] and all the options in the comments, and I've made comments in this demo with GRC fast attack times: https://jsbin.com/ropetu/edit?js,output

Comment: little problem: this `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` gets a score of 130. it should check for patterns, etc. that a hacker would think of.

Comment: Great method! Just adjusted a couple of things. Here: https://gist.github.com/stgogm/8a5edafa39f4d8d393520e2b40ee72e1

Comment: Worth mentioning that I've also added a password length check.

Comment: @tm_lv maybe you could put this properly licenced on github?

Comment: @Blauhirn - it's just a few lines, and i'm not very attached to them, so consider it unlicensed (https://choosealicense.com/licenses/unlicense/) and copies away :)

Comment: @tm_lv, Good stuff! Used it here: https://github.com/rnadler/ng2-password-strength-bar.

Comment: @YaakovAinspan That would be fairly difficult to do. You'd have to have a database of what you consider "patterns a hacker would think of". Easier said than done and highly subjective...You'd probably need to create some kind of json database file that could serve those patterns to the requestor too so that you don't have to compile some massive database into your script module. In my opinion, it's not really the strength meter's responsibility to tell the user that their password is common.

Comment: In case someone needs to convert this to Swift, here is an answer that helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60521043/5834643

Comment: Thanks for the algo! @JulienKronegg I noticed in my unitests, that `Tr0ub4dour&3` is a 83. Would you please share your mentioned 30% same letter occurrence variant here too? Thanks

Comment: @philk : about the 83, the answer has been edited after my comment which maybe explain the difference. About the 30%, I don't remember exactly (that's 7 years ago), but I would change the line `score += 5.0 / letters[pass[i]]` by `score += 5.0 / Math.min(1, letters[pass[i]] - pass.length*30/100)`. Disclaimer: not tested.

Comment: the problem with this and most answers is that the rank for `abcABC123!` = `jefPYM583^`

Comment: inspired by this, create a generic approach to char types, gave score to length, variation and mess: https://codepen.io/oriadam/pen/ExmaoYy
`abcABC123!`=34
`jefPYM583^`=78

Answer (score 36):

```
Password Strength Algorithm:

Password Length:
    5 Points: Less than 4 characters
    10 Points: 5 to 7 characters
    25 Points: 8 or more

Letters:
    0 Points: No letters
    10 Points: Letters are all lower case
    20 Points: Letters are upper case and lower case

Numbers:
    0 Points: No numbers
    10 Points: 1 number
    20 Points: 3 or more numbers

Characters:
    0 Points: No characters
    10 Points: 1 character
    25 Points: More than 1 character

Bonus:
    2 Points: Letters and numbers
    3 Points: Letters, numbers, and characters
    5 Points: Mixed case letters, numbers, and characters

Password Text Range:

    >= 90: Very Secure
    >= 80: Secure
    >= 70: Very Strong
    >= 60: Strong
    >= 50: Average
    >= 25: Weak
    >= 0: Very Weak
```

Settings
Toggle to true or false, if you want to change what is checked in the password

```
var m_strUpperCase = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
var m_strLowerCase = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var m_strNumber = "0123456789";
var m_strCharacters = "!@#$%^&*?_~"

Check password


function checkPassword(strPassword)
{
    // Reset combination count
    var nScore = 0;

    // Password length
    // -- Less than 4 characters
    if (strPassword.length < 5)
    {
        nScore += 5;
    }
    // -- 5 to 7 characters
    else if (strPassword.length > 4 && strPassword.length < 8)
    {
        nScore += 10;
    }
    // -- 8 or more
    else if (strPassword.length > 7)
    {
        nScore += 25;
    }

    // Letters
    var nUpperCount = countContain(strPassword, m_strUpperCase);
    var nLowerCount = countContain(strPassword, m_strLowerCase);
    var nLowerUpperCount = nUpperCount + nLowerCount;
    // -- Letters are all lower case
    if (nUpperCount == 0 && nLowerCount != 0) 
    { 
        nScore += 10; 
    }
    // -- Letters are upper case and lower case
    else if (nUpperCount != 0 && nLowerCount != 0) 
    { 
        nScore += 20; 
    }

    // Numbers
    var nNumberCount = countContain(strPassword, m_strNumber);
    // -- 1 number
    if (nNumberCount == 1)
    {
        nScore += 10;
    }
    // -- 3 or more numbers
    if (nNumberCount >= 3)
    {
        nScore += 20;
    }

    // Characters
    var nCharacterCount = countContain(strPassword, m_strCharacters);
    // -- 1 character
    if (nCharacterCount == 1)
    {
        nScore += 10;
    }   
    // -- More than 1 character
    if (nCharacterCount > 1)
    {
        nScore += 25;
    }

    // Bonus
    // -- Letters and numbers
    if (nNumberCount != 0 && nLowerUpperCount != 0)
    {
        nScore += 2;
    }
    // -- Letters, numbers, and characters
    if (nNumberCount != 0 && nLowerUpperCount != 0 && nCharacterCount != 0)
    {
        nScore += 3;
    }
    // -- Mixed case letters, numbers, and characters
    if (nNumberCount != 0 && nUpperCount != 0 && nLowerCount != 0 && nCharacterCount != 0)
    {
        nScore += 5;
    }


    return nScore;
}

// Runs password through check and then updates GUI 


function runPassword(strPassword, strFieldID) 
{
    // Check password
    var nScore = checkPassword(strPassword);


     // Get controls
        var ctlBar = document.getElementById(strFieldID + "_bar"); 
        var ctlText = document.getElementById(strFieldID + "_text");
        if (!ctlBar || !ctlText)
            return;

        // Set new width
        ctlBar.style.width = (nScore*1.25>100)?100:nScore*1.25 + "%";

    // Color and text
    // -- Very Secure
    /*if (nScore >= 90)
    {
        var strText = "Very Secure";
        var strColor = "#0ca908";
    }
    // -- Secure
    else if (nScore >= 80)
    {
        var strText = "Secure";
        vstrColor = "#7ff67c";
    }
    // -- Very Strong
    else 
    */
    if (nScore >= 80)
    {
        var strText = "Very Strong";
        var strColor = "#008000";
    }
    // -- Strong
    else if (nScore >= 60)
    {
        var strText = "Strong";
        var strColor = "#006000";
    }
    // -- Average
    else if (nScore >= 40)
    {
        var strText = "Average";
        var strColor = "#e3cb00";
    }
    // -- Weak
    else if (nScore >= 20)
    {
        var strText = "Weak";
        var strColor = "#Fe3d1a";
    }
    // -- Very Weak
    else
    {
        var strText = "Very Weak";
        var strColor = "#e71a1a";
    }

    if(strPassword.length == 0)
    {
    ctlBar.style.backgroundColor = "";
    ctlText.innerHTML =  "";
    }
else
    {
    ctlBar.style.backgroundColor = strColor;
    ctlText.innerHTML =  strText;
}
}

// Checks a string for a list of characters
function countContain(strPassword, strCheck)
{ 
    // Declare variables
    var nCount = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < strPassword.length; i++) 
    {
        if (strCheck.indexOf(strPassword.charAt(i)) > -1) 
        { 
                nCount++;
        } 
    } 

    return nCount; 
}
```

You can customize by yourself according to your requirement.

Comment: @garrow: What's wrong with the coding style other than being different from yours?  (FTR, it not the style I prefer either, but so what?)

Comment: Do you know origin of this given approach?

Comment: what happened to "2 numbers" ? :)

Comment: @Nicholas didn't get your question... Please elaborate...

Comment: Numbers:
    0 Points: No numbers
    10 Points: 1 number
    20 Points: 3 or more numbers

Comment: Let's try a test case! Bill's password is "123&$aA", about 40 bits of entropy according to wikipedia. Your algorithm gives it a score of 80. Alice's password is "eriahrieudfklsvhnsreuilvnreuhgsldhhvf", about 160 bits or entropy. Your algorithm ranks it 35.

Just to be clear, plugging those two passwords into https://www.grc.com/haystack.htm gives us 0.7 seconds to crack vs 74.72 thousand trillion trillion centuries.

Comment: Seriously though. You aren't at all concerned that your many times up-voted answer is going to suggest weaker passwords over stronger ones? People will copy paste this!

Comment: All other options are great, but the number one factor determining password strength is **length**. This should be reflected in the score. Anyway I think it's easy for people to customize this.