# jQuery password strength checker

Tags: javascript, jquery, passwords, logic

I'm quite new to jQuery, and I've written a simple function to check the strength of a password for each keypress.

The idea is that every time a user enters a character, the contents is evaluated to test the strengh of the password they have entered... I'm sure everyone has seen these before.

Anyhow, the logic I have used is that no password begins with a value of 1. When a lower-case character is used, the score increments to 2.  When a digit is used the score increments by 1 again, same for when an uppercase character is used and when the password becomes 5 or more characters long.

What is returned is the strength of the password so far as a value from 1 to 5 every time a key is pressed.

So, about my question.  The way that I've done it doesn't seem very jQuery like... almost like I may as well have just done straight javascript.  Also I was wondering about my logic.  Have I done anything done or overlooked something? Any suggestions from smarter people than myself?

Any suggestions or advice would be appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#pass_strength").keyup(function() {

            var strength = 1;

            /*length 5 characters or more*/
            if(this.value.length >= 5) {
                strength++;
            }

            /*contains lowercase characters*/
            if(this.value.match(/[a-z]+/)) {
                strength++;
            }

            /*contains digits*/
            if(this.value.match(/[0-9]+/)) {
                strength++;
            }

            /*contains uppercase characters*/
            if(this.value.match(/[A-Z]+/)) {
                strength++;
            }

            alert(strength);
        });
     });
```

Comment: [RnZ Code Labs](http://labs.rnzmedia.co.za) has an easy to use [Password Strength](http://labs.rnzmedia.co.za/password-strength) plugin.

Comment: for a more sophisticated password strength evaluator see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948172/password-strength-meter/11268104#11268104

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The best way is to take an existing plugin as TJB suggested.

As to your question about the code itself, a nicer way is to write it like that:

```
var pass = "f00Bar!";

var strength = 1;
var arr = [/.{5,}/, /[a-z]+/, /[0-9]+/, /[A-Z]+/];
jQuery.map(arr, function(regexp) {
  if(pass.match(regexp))
     strength++;
});
```

(Modified to correct syntax errors.)

Comment: Can you explain what this does: `/{5\,}/`

Comment: It should be `/.{5,}/`. The comma signifies "no upper limit". Without the comma it would try to match exactly 5 characters.

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest evaluating an existing jQuery password strength plugin. (unless your just doing it as an exercise)

Here are a few links I found:

[http://www.visual-blast.com/javascript/password-strength-checker/](http://web.archive.org/web/20150503115101/http://www.visual-blast.com/javascript/password-strength-checker/)

[http://phiras.wordpress.com/2007/04/08/password-strength-meter-a-jquery-plugin/](http://web.archive.org/web/20190225182459/http://phiras.wordpress.com/2007/04/08/password-strength-meter-a-jquery-plugin/)

Answer (score 2):

On top of gs' answer, you should check the password against common dictionary words (using a hash, probably). Otherwise a weak password like 'Yellow1' will be evaluated as strong by your logic.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing as excersie

Reference: [Password Strength Indicator](http://projects.sharkmediallc.com/pass/)

jQuery Code Used (# denotes what have changed from Benjamin's code)

```
$.fn.passwordStrength = function( options ){
return this.each(function(){
    var that = this;that.opts = {};
    that.opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.passwordStrength.defaults, options);

    that.div = $(that.opts.targetDiv);
    that.defaultClass = that.div.attr('class');

    that.percents = (that.opts.classes.length) ? 100 / that.opts.classes.length : 100;

    v = $(this)
    .keyup(function(){
        if( typeof el == "undefined" )
        this.el = $(this);
        var s = getPasswordStrength (this.value);
        var p = this.percents;
        var t = Math.floor( s / p );

        if( 100 <= s )
        t = this.opts.classes.length - 1;

        this.div
        .removeAttr('class')
        .addClass( this.defaultClass )
        .addClass( this.opts.classes[ t ] );
    })
    # Removed generate password button creation
});

function getPasswordStrength(H){
    var D=(H.length);

    # Added below to make all passwords less than 4 characters show as weak
    if (D<4) { D=0 }


    if(D>5){
        D=5
    }
    var F=H.replace(/[0-9]/g,"");
    var G=(H.length-F.length);
    if(G>3){G=3}
    var A=H.replace(/\W/g,"");
    var C=(H.length-A.length);
    if(C>3){C=3}
    var B=H.replace(/[A-Z]/g,"");
    var I=(H.length-B.length);
    if(I>3){I=3}
    var E=((D*10)-20)+(G*10)+(C*15)+(I*10);
    if(E<0){E=0}
    if(E>100){E=100}
    return E
}


# Removed generate password function
};

$(document)
.ready(function(){
$('input[name="password2"]').passwordStrength({targetDiv: '#iSM',classes : Array('weak','medium','strong')});

});
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't want to use jQuery you can use something like this:

```js
function strengthResult(p) {
if(p.length<6 || p.length>18) {
return 'Passwords must be 6-18 characters';
}
var strength = checkStrength(p);
switch(true) {
    case strength<=30:
        return 'Password "'+p+'" ('+strength+') is Very Weak';
        break;
    case strength>30 && strength<=35:
        return 'Password "'+p+'" ('+strength+') is Weak';
        break;
    case strength>35 && strength<=50:
        return 'Password "'+p+'" ('+strength+') is below Average';
        break;        
    case strength>50 && strength<=60:
        return 'Password "'+p+'" ('+strength+') is almost Good';
        break;
    case strength>60 && strength<=70:
        return 'Password "'+p+'" ('+strength+') is Good';
        break;
    case strength>70 && strength<=80:
        return 'Password "'+p+'" ('+strength+') is Very Good';
        break;
    case strength>80 && strength<=90:
        return 'Password "'+p+'" ('+strength+') is Strong';
        break;
    case strength>90 && strength<=100:
        return 'Password "'+p+'" ('+strength+') is Very Strong';
        break;
        default:
    return 'Error';
}
}
function strengthMap(w,arr) {
var c = 0;
var sum = 0;
newArray = arr.map(function(i) {
i = c;
//sum += w-2*i;
sum += w;
c++;
return sum;
});
return newArray[c-1];
}
function checkStrength(p){
var weight;
var extra;
switch(true) {
    case p.length<6:
        return false;
        break;
    case p.length>18:
        return false;
        break;
    case p.length>=6 && p.length<=10:
      weight = 7;
        extra = 4;
        break;
    case p.length>10 && p.length<=14:
      weight = 6;
        extra = 3;
        break;
    case p.length>14 && p.length<=18:
      weight = 5;
        extra = 2.5;
        break;
}
allDigits = p.replace( /\D+/g, '');
allLower = p.replace( /[^a-z]/g, '' );
allUpper = p.replace( /[^A-Z]/g, '' );
allSpecial = p.replace( /[^\W]/g, '' );
if(allDigits && typeof allDigits!=='undefined') {
dgtArray = Array.from(new Set(allDigits.split('')));
dgtStrength = strengthMap(weight,dgtArray);
} else {
dgtStrength = 0;
}
if(allLower && typeof allLower!=='undefined') {
lowArray = Array.from(new Set(allLower.split('')));
lowStrength = strengthMap(weight,lowArray);
} else {
lowStrength = 0;
}
if(allUpper && typeof allUpper!=='undefined') {
upArray = Array.from(new Set(allUpper.split('')));
upStrength = strengthMap(weight,upArray);
} else {
upStrength = 0;
}
if(allSpecial && typeof allSpecial!=='undefined') {
splArray = Array.from(new Set(allSpecial.split('')));
splStrength = strengthMap(weight,splArray);
} else {
splStrength = 0;
}
strength = dgtStrength+lowStrength+upStrength+splStrength;
if(dgtArray.length>0){
strength = strength + extra;
}
if(splStrength.length>0){
strength = strength + extra;
}
if(p.length>=6){
strength = strength + extra;
}
if(lowArray.length>0 && upArray.length>0){
strength = strength + extra;
}
return strength;
}
console.log(strengthResult('5@aKw1'));
console.log(strengthResult('5@aKw13'));
console.log(strengthResult('5@aKw13e'));
console.log(strengthResult('5@aKw13eE'));
console.log(strengthResult('5@aKw13eE!'));
console.log(strengthResult('5@aKw13eE!,'));
console.log(strengthResult('5@aKw13eE!,4'));
console.log(strengthResult('5@aKw13eE!,4D'));
console.log(strengthResult('5@aKw13eE!,4Dq'));
console.log(strengthResult('5@aKw13eE!,4DqJ'));
console.log(strengthResult('5@aKw13eE!,4DqJi'));
console.log(strengthResult('5@aKw13eE!,4DqJi#'));
console.log(strengthResult('5@aKw13eE!,4DqJi#7'));
console.log(strengthResult('5@aKw13eE!,4DqJJ#7'));
console.log(strengthResult('5@aKw33eE!,4DqJJ#7'));

console.log(strengthResult('111111'));
console.log(strengthResult('1111111'));
console.log(strengthResult('11111111'));
console.log(strengthResult('111111111'));
console.log(strengthResult('1111111111'));
console.log(strengthResult('11111111111'));
console.log(strengthResult('111111111111'));
console.log(strengthResult('1111111111111'));
console.log(strengthResult('11111111111111'));
console.log(strengthResult('111111111111111'));
console.log(strengthResult('1111111111111111'));
console.log(strengthResult('11111111111111111'));
console.log(strengthResult('111111111111111111'));

console.log(strengthResult('5@aKw33eE!,4DqJJ#71'));
console.log(strengthResult('11111'));
```

the above snippet will calculate password strength for passwords from 6 to 18 characters in length. The default value for each unique character is

- **7 points** if password 6-10 characters
- **6 points** if password 10-14 characters
- **5 points** if password 14-18 characters

If a character is repeated in password then it looses 2 points for every repetition.

Extra points are given when the following specifications are met:

- password **has at least 6 digits** (adds 2.5 or 3 or 4 points)
- password **has at least 1 number** (adds 2.5 or 3 or 4 points)
- password **has at least 1 special character** (adds 2.5 or 3 or 4 points)
- password **has at least 1 upper-case and 1 lower-case character** (adds 2.5 or 3 or 4
  points)

Answer (score 1):

- The length of the password should be at least 8 characters.
- The strength increases with the length, a longer password should have more points.
- Include special characters like #/" and the like. (Or just any other than  [a-Z0-9])
- For really long passwords this method could get slow. Why don't you just test every new character and use a dictionary for which features the password already has.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the jQuery plugins for password strength check

Some of them are

[Password Strength Meter](http://phiras.wordpress.com/2007/04/08/password-strength-meter-a-jquery-plugin/)

[Password Strength Indicator](http://projects.sharkmediallc.com/pass/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to check the password for text box

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('#pwd').keyup(function()
{
$('#strength_message').html(checkStrength($('#pwd').val()))
}) 
function checkStrength(password)
{
var strength = 0
if (password.length < 6) { 
$('#strength_message').removeClass()
$('#strength_message').addClass('short')
return 'Too short' 
}

if (password.length > 7) strength += 1
if (password.match(/([a-z].*[A-Z])|([A-Z].*[a-z])/))  strength += 1
if (password.match(/([a-zA-Z])/) && password.match(/([0-9])/))  strength += 1 
if (password.match(/([!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/))  strength += 1
if (password.match(/(.*[!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~].*[!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/)) strength += 1
if (strength < 2 )
{
$('#strength_message').removeClass()
$('#strength_message').addClass('weak')
return 'Weak'   
}
else if (strength == 2 )
{
$('#strength_message').removeClass()
$('#strength_message').addClass('good')
return 'Good'  
}
else
{
$('#strength_message').removeClass()
$('#strength_message').addClass('strong')
return 'Strong'
}
}
});
</script>
```

**Html:**

```
   <center><form id="password-strength">
    <label>Password : </label>
    <input name="pwd" id="pwd" type="password"/>
    <span id="strength_message"></span>
    </form><br/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function strengthResult(p) {
if(p.length<6 || p.length>18) {
return 'Passwords must be 6-18 characters';
}
var strength = checkStrength(p);
switch(true) {
    case strength<=30:
        return 'Password "'+p+'" ('+strength+') is Very Weak';
        break;
    case strength>30 && strength<=35:
        return 'Password "'+p+'" ('+strength+') is Weak';
        break;
    case strength>35 && strength<=50:
        return 'Password "'+p+'" ('+strength+') is below Average';
        break;        
    case strength>50 && strength<=60:
        return 'Password "'+p+'" ('+strength+') is almost Good';
        break;
    case strength>60 && strength<=70:
        return 'Password "'+p+'" ('+strength+') is Good';
        break;
    case strength>70 && strength<=80:
        return 'Password "'+p+'" ('+strength+') is Very Good';
        break;
    case strength>80 && strength<=90:
        return 'Password "'+p+'" ('+strength+') is Strong';
        break;
    case strength>90 && strength<=100:
        return 'Password "'+p+'" ('+strength+') is Very Strong';
        break;
        default:
    return 'Error';
}
}
function strengthMap(w,arr) {
var c = 0;
var sum = 0;
newArray = arr.map(function(i) {
i = c;
//sum += w-2*i;
sum += w;
c++;
return sum;
});
return newArray[c-1];
}
function checkStrength(p){
var weight;
var extra;
switch(true) {
    case p.length<6:
        return false;
        break;
    case p.length>18:
        return false;
        break;
    case p.length>=6 && p.length<=10:
      weight = 7;
        extra = 4;
        break;
    case p.length>10 && p.length<=14:
      weight = 6;
        extra = 3;
        break;
    case p.length>14 && p.length<=18:
      weight = 5;
        extra = 2.5;
        break;
}
allDigits = p.replace( /\D+/g, '');
allLower = p.replace( /[^a-z]/g, '' );
allUpper = p.replace( /[^A-Z]/g, '' );
allSpecial = p.replace( /[^\W]/g, '' );
if(allDigits && typeof allDigits!=='undefined') {
dgtArray = Array.from(new Set(allDigits.split('')));
dgtStrength = strengthMap(weight,dgtArray);
} else {
dgtStrength = 0;
}
if(allLower && typeof allLower!=='undefined') {
lowArray = Array.from(new Set(allLower.split('')));
lowStrength = strengthMap(weight,lowArray);
} else {
lowStrength = 0;
}
if(allUpper && typeof allUpper!=='undefined') {
upArray = Array.from(new Set(allUpper.split('')));
upStrength = strengthMap(weight,upArray);
} else {
upStrength = 0;
}
if(allSpecial && typeof allSpecial!=='undefined') {
splArray = Array.from(new Set(allSpecial.split('')));
splStrength = strengthMap(weight,splArray);
} else {
splStrength = 0;
}
strength = dgtStrength+lowStrength+upStrength+splStrength;
if(dgtArray.length>0){
strength = strength + extra;
}
if(splStrength.length>0){
strength = strength + extra;
}
if(p.length>=6){
strength = strength + extra;
}
if(lowArray.length>0 && upArray.length>0){
strength = strength + extra;
}
return strength;
}
console.log(strengthResult('5@aKw1'));
console.log(strengthResult('5@aKw13'));
console.log(strengthResult('5@aKw13e'));
console.log(strengthResult('5@aKw13eE'));
console.log(strengthResult('5@aKw13eE!'));
console.log(strengthResult('5@aKw13eE!,'));
console.log(strengthResult('5@aKw13eE!,4'));
console.log(strengthResult('5@aKw13eE!,4D'));
console.log(strengthResult('5@aKw13eE!,4Dq'));
console.log(strengthResult('5@aKw13eE!,4DqJ'));
console.log(strengthResult('5@aKw13eE!,4DqJi'));
console.log(strengthResult('5@aKw13eE!,4DqJi#'));
console.log(strengthResult('5@aKw13eE!,4DqJi#7'));
console.log(strengthResult('5@aKw13eE!,4DqJJ#7'));
console.log(strengthResult('5@aKw33eE!,4DqJJ#7'));

console.log(strengthResult('111111'));
console.log(strengthResult('1111111'));
console.log(strengthResult('11111111'));
console.log(strengthResult('111111111'));
console.log(strengthResult('1111111111'));
console.log(strengthResult('11111111111'));
console.log(strengthResult('111111111111'));
console.log(strengthResult('1111111111111'));
console.log(strengthResult('11111111111111'));
console.log(strengthResult('111111111111111'));
console.log(strengthResult('1111111111111111'));
console.log(strengthResult('11111111111111111'));
console.log(strengthResult('111111111111111111'));

console.log(strengthResult('5@aKw33eE!,4DqJJ#71'));
console.log(strengthResult('11111'));
```

Comment: It is better to give a brief explanation along with your code.

Comment: Unless you have something very specific to add I wouldn't recommend adding an answer to a 9 year old question

Comment: Just note, this is the exact same code as the accepted answer someone posted two years earlier without the explanation.

Comment: nice! my scoring function uses a very similar approach - bonus for variation, mess and length: https://codepen.io/oriadam/pen/ExmaoYy
tried the same set, results are similar. only that i gave too much score to `1111111111111111` (31)

Answer (score 0):

Below is a free password strength/policy JQuery plug-in validator. It is also supports validation of passwords entered in multiple languages (supported in Unicode). It is multilingual.

[Password Policy/Strength JQuery plug-in Validator](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f9935e/4718/Default.aspx?ArticleID=8d0f0bee-dadd-4610-88c0-8088dafd95c9)

Answer (score 0):

Strength of a password should be checked on behalf of several parameters like the presence of special characters and numbers, length of the password etc.

I have found the below tutorial with nice demo:

http://tinytute.com/2014/06/03/animated-password-strength-checker-quick-easy/

The jQuery code block:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#textBox").keyup(function(){

        var passWord = $("#textBox").val();
        var passLength = passWord.length;
        var specialFlag = 0;
        var numberFlag = 0;
        var numberGenerator = 0;
        var total = 0;

        if(/^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/.test(passWord) == false) {

            specialFlag =20;
        }


        if(passWord.match(/[0-9]/)) {

            numberFlag = 25;
        }

        if(passLength>4&&passLength<=6){
            numberGenerator =25;
        }else if(passLength>=7&&passLength<=9){
            numberGenerator =35;
        }else if(passLength>9){
            numberGenerator =55;
        }else if(passLength>0&&passLength<=4){
            numberGenerator =15;
        }else{
            numberGenerator =0;
        }

        total = numberGenerator + specialFlag + numberFlag;
        if(total<30){
            $('#progressBar').css('background-color','#CCC');
        }else if(total<60&&total>=30){

            $('#progressBar').css('background-color','#FF6600');

        }else if(total>=60&&total<90){

            $('#progressBar').css('background-color','#FFCC00');

        }else if(total>=90){

            $('#progressBar').css('background-color','#0f0');

        }
        $('#progressBar').css('width',total+'%');

    });

});
```

Hope these set of logic will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

best way is this

```js
function password_validate(txt) {
  var val1 = 0;
  var val2 = 0;
  var val3 = 0;
  var val4 = 0;
  var val5 = 0;
  var counter, color, result;
  var flag = false;
  if (txt.value.length <= 0) {
    counter = 0;
    color = "transparent";
    result = "";
  }
  if (txt.value.length < 8 & txt.value.length > 0) {
    counter = 20;
    color = "red";
    result = "Short";
  } else {
    document.getElementById(txt.id + "error").innerHTML = " ";
    txt.style.borderColor = "grey";
    var regex = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?!.*\s).{8,15}$/;
    //  document.getElementById("pass_veri").style.display="block";
    var fletter = /[a-z]/;
    if (fletter.test(txt.value)) {
      val1 = 20;

    } else {
      val1 = 0;
    }
    //macth special character
    var special_char = /[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/]/;
    if (special_char.test(txt.value)) {
      val2 = 30;
    } else {
      val = 0;
    }
    /*capital_letter*/
    var cap_lett = /[A-Z]/;
    if (cap_lett.test(txt.value)) {
      val3 = 20;
    } else {
      val = 0;
    }
    /*one numeric*/
    var num = /[0-9]/;
    if (num.test(txt.value)) {
      val4 = 20;
    } else {
      val4 = 0;
    }
    /* 8-15 character*/
    var range = /^.{8,50}$/;
    if (range.test(txt.value)) {
      val5 = 10;
    } else {
      val5 = 0;
    }
    counter = val1 + val2 + val3 + val4 + val5;

    if (counter >= 30) {
      color = "skyblue";
      result = "Fair";
    }
    if (counter >= 50) {
      color = "gold";
      result = "Good";
    }
    if (counter >= 80) {
      color = "green";
      result = "Strong";
    }
    if (counter >= 90) {
      color = "green";
      result = "Very Strong";
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("prog").style.width = counter + "%";
  document.getElementById("prog").style.backgroundColor = color;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
  document.getElementById("result").style.color = color;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Rajdhani', sans-serif;
  background-color: #E4E4E4;
}


/* tooltip*/

.hint {
  width: 258px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #CC9933;
  background-color: #FFFFCC;
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.hint:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 24px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 17px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  border-left: 22px solid #CC9933;
}

.hint:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 26px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 14px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  border-left: 20px solid #FFFFCC;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.progress {
  height: 7px;
}

#progres {
  display: block;
}

p {
  margin: 0px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.form-control {
  width: none;
  margin-left: 260px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-group col-lg-12 parent ">
  <label class="hint" id="pass-hint">
    Password Strength:<span id="result"></span>
    <br>
    <div class="progress" id="progres">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" id="prog">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p> passowrd must have atleast 8 charatcer</p>
  </label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" id="pass" onfocus="document.getElementById('pass-hint').style.display='block'" onblur="document.getElementById('pass-hint').style.display='none'" placeholder="**********"
    oninput="password_validate(this);document.getElementById('progres').style.display='block';">
  <i class=" form-control-feedback" id="passsuccess" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <span id="passerror" class="help-block error"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find complete code below:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.complexify.min.js"></script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
<h4> Password strength check with jquery</h4>
<label>Enter Storng Password: </label>
<input type="password" id="pwd"><br/>
<progress style="margin-left:20%" value="0" max="100" id="pg"></progress> <span id="cpx">0%</span>
</div>
```

Script

```
$(function(){
$("#pwd").complexify({}, function(valid, complexity){
//console.log("Password complexity: " + Math.round(complexity));
$("#pg").val(Math.round(complexity));
$("#cpx").html(Math.round(complexity)+'%');
});
});
```

Please complete working source code [here](https://jsonworld.com/demo/how-to-check-password-strength-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

I have found an good design with password validator plugin. let me explain the steps

here is the full code : https://lets-solve.com/jquery-password-validator/

1. Create HTML file and place password and confirm password field field.

2. load css
3. load javascript

4. Initialize the plugin

   var password_validator = new PasswordValidator();

Thats it, now password matcher will show error message if both passwords not match.

How to compare & validate password while submiting form/click on button?

```
var password_validator = new PasswordValidator();
```

// to check password criteria is matching, if yes than it will return true otherwise returns false
var is_valid = password_validator.is_valid();

// to check both passwords are matching or not
var is_match = password_validator.match_confirm_password();

Answer (score 0):

implementation for scoring based on variation, mess and length:

```
function scorePass(pass) {  
    let score = 0;
    
    // variation range
    score += new Set(pass.split("")).size * 1;
    const charCodes = [...new Set(pass.split(''))].map(x=>x.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0));

    // shuffle score - bonus for messing things up
    for (let i=1; i < charCodes.length;i++)
    {
        const dist = Math.abs(charCodes[i-1]-charCodes[i]);
        if (dist>60)
            score += 15;
        else if (dist>8)
            score += 10;
        else if (dist>1)
            score += 2;
    }
    
    // bonus for length
    score += (pass.length - 6) * 3;

    return parseInt(score);
}
```

`abcעfדg94a` > `jefPYM583^` > `abcABC!@#$`

https://codepen.io/oriadam/pen/ExmaoYy