# visual jquery rule-based password indicator

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, passwords

I am looking for a jquery plugin that does the following

1. When click on a text box, a div pop up next to it with all rules about a password
2. As user type along, each rules that is passed get a check mark beside them
3. popup disappears when the text box lose focus

I am seeing a lot of password strength indicator that shows a generic weak->strong bar, however this tells the user little information about what they are doing wrong.

If there are no existing one out there, then I'll have to roll my own.  Just wanted to check before I dive into it.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search pointed me here:

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/10-password-strength-meter-scripts-for-a-better-registration-interface/

I have never used any of these, but might be worth checking out.

**Edit**

See also:

[jQuery password strength checker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388609/jquery-password-strength-checker)