# Password strength via regular express?

Tags: asp.net, regex

I would like to use a regular expression in the ASP.NET membership. What is a regular express for the below?

- at least 8 characters long
- include at least one upper case letter
- one lower case letter
- one number

Comment: If you are also interested in doing that client side this might interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388609/jquery-password-strength-checker And you could actually use the different part of the expression wrote in this thread and check the password strengh gradually on your server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
^((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like that:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z\d=:;<>,~!@#\\$%/^&)(\[\]+-]{8,}$
```

Test it [here](http://www.gethifi.com/tools/regex).
You may also want to learn about the "?=" thing, which is called "positive lookahead" [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).
In short, when all three lookaheads (`.*\d` and `.*[a-z]` and `.*[A-Z]`) are matched (and are discarded), the main regex `[a-zA-Z\d=:;<>,~!@#\\$%/^&)(\[\]+-]{8,}` can be matched too.

Comment: Why restrict the valid characters? That wasn't in the spec. Also, your explanation is incorrect. The lookaheads don't follow the regex match.

Comment: Agreed partly, but not all of the characters are valid. We do not have a valid characters list, so I placed the most strict restriction. I did not say lookaheads follow regex match. I'll try to fix the misunderstanding)

Comment: So you want to force users to use passwords that are less safe? Why?

Comment: My decision is based on unknown storage restrictions and on the fact this is an example. It could be just ".{8,}", or he could add the special character he wants to be allowed.

Comment: Added some more allowed characters as suggested by Tim Pietzcker .

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to do this in one regex? I would make each of those rules one regex, and test for them individually. I suspect you code will end up being simpler, and you'll save yourself and whoever has to maintain your application several headaches.

Comment: I realize what your saying.. the thing is this is a textbox field for a software system.