# How can I use JavaScript to test for password strength in a way that returns the quality of the password in numeric form?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the challenge below:

> Write an algorithm to check the validity of a password inputed by a
>   user with the criteria below.
>
> If these criteria at met, the user is returned a percentage value of
>   how strong his/her password is:
>
> ●At least 1 letter between lowercase  [ a - z ]  ->  25%
>
> ●At least 1 letter between uppercase [ A - Z ]  ->  25%
>
> ●At least 1 number between [ 0 - 9 ] -> 25%
>
> ●At least 1 character from [ $@#&! ] -> 25%
>
> If  these criteria are met, the user is sent a message according to
>   condition met:
>
> ●Minimum length of password is 6 (display a message)
>
> ●Maximum length of password is 12

For Html:

```
<body>

  <form class="center-block">

<input type="text" id="password" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-lg">

<progress max="100" value="0" id="meter"></progress>

<button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">Show Password Strength</button>

</form>

  <div class="textbox text-center"> password </div>
  
</body>
```

For JavaScript:

```
var code
=document.getElementById("password");

var strengthbar= document.getElementById("meter");

code.addEventListener("keyup", function(){checkpassword(code.value)

    })
 var display =document.getElementsByClassName("textbox")[0];
    function checkpassword(password)
    {
    var strength=0;
    if (password.match(/[a-z]+/)){
        strength+=1;
    }
    if (password.match(/[A-Z]+/)){
        strength+=1;
    }
    if (password.match(/[0-9]+/)){
        strength+=1;
    }
    if (password.match(/[$@#&!]+/)){
        strength+=1;

        }
    if (password.length<6){
    display.innerHTML="minimum number of characters is 6":
    }

    if (password.length>12){
            display.innerHTML="maximum number of characters is 12";
}
    switch(strength){
    case 0:
        strengthbar.value=0;
        break;

    case 1:
        strengthbar.value=25;
        break;

    case 2:
        strengthbar.value=50;
        break;

    case 3:
        strengthbar.value=75;
        break;

    case 4:
        strengthbar.value=100;
        break; }
}
```

Above is my own solution to the problem. It isn't giving me any errors but the JavaScript is not generating any results on my html.

[Here is a link to the pen I'm using](https://codepen.io/Ojomiba/pen/vjoxRG)

Comment: What exactly does not work? Any errors in your dev console?

Comment: You've not yet explained a problem (no, *not working* is not a problem description until you clearly explain what *not working* means) or asked a specific question (no, *why is my code not working* is not a specific question).

Comment: @CodeF0x No errors at all. Yet it doesn't work on code pen where I'm trying it.

Comment: You should have a look at how to create a MCVE : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: user20490, you should clean your question, remove everything that's not related to your specific bug. Create the minimal example that reproduces the fact that it's not working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948172/password-strength-meter

Comment: You should have errors as `document.getElementByClassName("textbox");` is not a function. It's `getElementsByClassName` and should return an array like object. You also are not defining `strengthbar` anywhere in the code presented.

Comment: Please don't do what? Ask you to improve your question? I wouldn't have to ask you to improve it if you posted it properly in the first place. How is it my fault you didn't?

Comment: I gave it a chance by asking you to improve it. What more do you expect me to do?

Comment: @user20490 first off the challenge info is extraneous information. You also should only provide the pertinent html to your js, structure is unimportant. You need to clearly state where you are trying to output to your html and some basic debugging such as that you have verified via console.logs or breakpoints that you are getting to the code that is doing the work. You can help yourself out by researching basic js debugging.

Comment: @KenWhite I'm sure you don't mean it, but you look a little bit too rude. Asking a close vote, and guiding users to the help page is enough. I remember having been worse when I came here first, I'm glad I did not met angry people.

Comment: @user20490 look at Scrappedcola answers, they are probably more valuable than you think, your solution is in.

Comment: And due to previously mentioned fact about `document.getElementsById` being not a singular item `display.innerhtml` should also throw an error as innerhtml is not a property of a list like that.

Comment: you can that would generally help. also typo with `innerhtml` should be `innerHTML`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6ou7wzc4/ hit f12 to open console. You will see right away that your first error is in the switch case. You fix that (lovely use of {}) you will see your next error is the innerhtml issue. Keep goig through and updating until your console is clean

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe: Not being rude. I left a polite comment that asked the poster to improve the question, and got *Please don't do that* in response. I was by no means rude; I asked the poster to clarify what exactly it was they did not want me to do. Comments are designed precisely for asking the poster to clarify details. I also haven't posted anything on this question for more than half an hour now, until you caused me to do so. Thanks for  your input, though. When using a comment exactly as intended for asking for clarification becomes being rude, SO is lost.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You had several mistakes in your code (had because you fixed some by reading the comments). I'll list them again anyways:

- Your `switch` statement was missing a curly bracket (`{`) at its beginning
- Your function was missing a curly bracket (`{`) at its end
- It's `getElementsByClassName`, not `getElementByClassName`. In addition to that, `getElementsByClassName` returns an array like HTMLCollection, so you need to select the first one like this: `getElementsByClassName('textbox')[0]` (mind the "[0]" here)
- You don't call `innerHTML` like `innerHTML("bla");`, it's `innerHTML = "bla";`

You also should always use semicolons (`;`).

```js
var code = document.getElementById("password");

var strengthbar = document.getElementById("meter");
var display = document.getElementsByClassName("textbox")[0];

code.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  checkpassword(code.value);
});


function checkpassword(password) {
  var strength = 0;
  if (password.match(/[a-z]+/)) {
    strength += 1;
  }
  if (password.match(/[A-Z]+/)) {
    strength += 1;
  }
  if (password.match(/[0-9]+/)) {
    strength += 1;
  }
  if (password.match(/[$@#&!]+/)) {
    strength += 1;

  }

  if (password.length < 6) {
    display.innerHTML = "minimum number of characters is 6";
  }

  if (password.length > 12) {
    display.innerHTML = "maximum number of characters is 12";
  }

  switch (strength) {
    case 0:
      strengthbar.value = 0;
      break;

    case 1:
      strengthbar.value = 25;
      break;

    case 2:
      strengthbar.value = 50;
      break;

    case 3:
      strengthbar.value = 75;
      break;

    case 4:
      strengthbar.value = 100;
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

  <form class="center-block">

    <input type="text" id="password" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-lg">

    <progress max="100" value="0" id="meter"></progress>

    <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">Show Password Strength</button>

  </form>

  <div class="textbox text-center"> password </div>

</body>
```

Comment: It says "a@1A" is very strong password... You should also check letters count.