# How to Convert JS Password Strength Meter to Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to convert this javascript password score function to swift, so I can use the same logic on mobile as we do on web.   Here is the [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HFMvX/) with the code to test:

```
function scorePassword(pass) {
    var score = 0;
    if (!pass)
      return score;
    // award every unique letter until 5 repetitions
    var letters = new Object();
    for (var i=0; i<pass.length; i++) {
      letters[pass[i]] = (letters[pass[i]] || 0) + 1;
      score += 5.0 / letters[pass[i]];
    }
    // bonus points for mixing it up
    var variations = {
      digits: /\d/.test(pass),
      lower: /[a-z]/.test(pass),
      upper: /[A-Z]/.test(pass),
      nonWords: /\W/.test(pass),
    }
    variationCount = 0;
    for (var check in variations) {
      variationCount += (variations[check] == true) ? 1 : 0;
    }
    score += (variationCount - 1) * 10;
    return parseInt(score);
}

function checkPassStrength(pass) {
    var score = scorePassword(pass);
    if (score > 80)    
      return "Strong";    
    if (score > 60)
      return "Good";
    if (score >= 30)
      return "Weak";    
    return "";
}
```

I'm having an issue in converting this part:

```
var letters = new Object();
for (var i=0; i<pass.length; i++) {
    letters[pass[i]] = (letters[pass[i]] || 0) + 1;
    score += 5.0 / letters[pass[i]];
}
```

I've tried to create a dictionary to store the character as key and then increment the value with each occurrences of that key, but it's not working as expected.

```
let string = "Testing22!"
var score = 0
var dictionary = [String.Element: Int]()
for x in string {
    let value = dictionary[x] ?? 0
    dictionary[x] = value + 1
    score += 5 / value
}
print(dictionary) //["s": 1, "T": 1, "g": 1, "2": 2, "n": 1, "i": 1, "!": 1, "t": 1, "e": 1]
print(score)
```

I'm also not sure of the most efficient way to handle the regex checks for the bonus points section.

Comment: Looks like you have `score += 5 / value` but it should be `score += 5 / value + 1`

Comment: Also you really want `5.0` as in the original code, because `5/Int` will be an intreger division so your score will be 2 if there are 2 entries in the map rather than 2.5. Alternatively, explicitly type `score` as a `Float` (that way the literal `5` will be interpreted as a float as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd port it over to swift like this, I'm sure there are some improvements to be made, but thats a quick conversion:

```
func scorePassword(_ inputString: String?) -> Double {
    var score: Double = 0
    guard let string = inputString, !string.isEmpty else { return score }

    // award every unique letter until 5 repetitions
    let countedSet = NSCountedSet()
    for x in string {
        countedSet.add(x)
        score += 5.0 / Double(countedSet.count(for: x))
    }

    // bonus points for mixing it up
    let variations = [
        "^(?=.*[0-9]).*$",
        "^(?=.*[a-z]).*$",
        "^(?=.*[A-Z]).*$",
        "^(?=.*\\W).*$"
    ]

    var variationCount: Double = 0
    for check in variations {
        print(string.testRegex(check))
        variationCount += string.testRegex(check) ? 1 : 0
    }
    score += (variationCount - 1) * 10

    return floor(score)
}

func checkPassStrength(_ inputString: String?) -> String {
    let score = scorePassword(inputString)
    if score > 80 {
        return "Strong"
    } else if score > 60 {
        return "Good"
    } else if score > 30 {
        return "Weak"
    }
    return ""
}

extension String {
    func testRegex(_ regex: String) -> Bool {
        let test = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", regex)
        return test.evaluate(with: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run js code inside Swift and get the result from it, so you can share code between platforms.

```
let jsSource = """
    function scorePassword(pass) {
    var score = 0;
    if (!pass)
    return score;
    // award every unique letter until 5 repetitions
    var letters = new Object();
    for (var i=0; i<pass.length; i++) {
    letters[pass[i]] = (letters[pass[i]] || 0) + 1;
    score += 5.0 / letters[pass[i]];
    }
    // bonus points for mixing it up
    var variations = {
    digits: /d/.test(pass),
    lower: /[a-z]/.test(pass),
    upper: /[A-Z]/.test(pass),
    nonWords: /W/.test(pass),
    }
    variationCount = 0;
    for (var check in variations) {
    variationCount += (variations[check] == true) ? 1 : 0;
    }
    score += (variationCount - 1) * 10;
    return parseInt(score);
    }

    function checkPassStrength(pass) {
    var score = scorePassword(pass);
    if (score > 80)
    return "Strong";
    if (score > 60)
    return "Good";
    if (score >= 30)
    return "Weak";
    return "";
    }
    """

    let context = JSContext()
    context?.evaluateScript(jsSource)

    let testFunction = context?.objectForKeyedSubscript("scorePassword")
    let result = testFunction?.call(withArguments: ["1234"])
    print("js result : " , result )
```

Note; I edited the part "digits: /\d/.test(pass)" to "digits: /d/.test(pass)"